# Symfony disable controller actions in production

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Is it possible to "disable" specific actions when the prod environment is active?

I have a few test actions which shouldn't be executed in a production environment.

```
class TestController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\Get("/api/test", name="api_test")
     */
    public function testAction(Request $request)
    {
        // something
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know of a way in annotations, I've always preferred to use the config files - if you use those you could just add the dev routes in `routing_dev.yml`

Comment: Or check the environment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640866/accessing-the-appkernel-environment-variable-in-symfony-2

Comment: @JimL ho can I do it? I am using routing annotations.

Comment: Um, I specifically said I did not know a way to do it with annotations

Comment: @JimL yes I know, sorry I meant "How can you you do that without annotations?". Thanks.

Comment: Like I said, load routes from the config files and add them to `routing_dev.yml`. Examples here https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a third party by Qandidate-labs called toggle.
https://github.com/qandidate-labs/qandidate-toggle-bundle

The toggle can be set up based off an entry in your parameters.yml file Or I suspect you could do it based on the env

And then at the top of the method you just use the annotation similar to below:

```
/**
 * @Toggle("another-cool-feature")
 */
public function barAction()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1: Check the environment in the controller

```
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $env = $this->container->get( 'kernel' )->getEnvironment()

    if ($env !== 'dev') {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
    }

    //your action
}
```

## Option 2: Only include the route in development environment

For this options, let me rephrase your question: How to **enable** controllers in **development** environment? (instead of disable in production)

Take a look at the [Symfony Standard Edition](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard), "a fully-functional Symfony application that you can use as the skeleton for your new applications.". It features a dev environment that includes routes for WebProfilerBundle (a.k.a. Web Debug Toolbar).

In your `dev` environment, [config_dev.yml](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/3.3/app/config/config_dev.yml) is being loaded. You can define a routing file that extends the main router:

> config_dev.yml

```
framework:
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing_dev.yml'
        strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }
```

> routing_dev.yml

```
test:
    resource: '@TestBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

Comment: Hello, what if I have my TestController inside my AppBundle? Do I need to move it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how 'complicated' your TestController is, but maybe you want to create a TestBundle which is added to the AppKernel in the dev/test environment only (see `AppKernel::registerBundles`).

Comment: I'll look if you can 'exclude' a particular Controller if you include a directory like my example.