# Is it possible to List Out All the Global variables in PHP?

Tags: php, global-variables

Is it possible to list out all the Global Variable. Such , as to print all session variable we can use `print_r($_SESSION);` as the same way, if i want to know how many Global variables are define in my site. is it possible?  Please Help.

I need the list which can show me all the Global variables List in PHP.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, PHP `$GLOBALS` array will show you.

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";
print_r($GLOBALS);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It throws `500 server error`. Meanwhile `var_dump($GLOBALS);` works. (hook: 'shutdown')
Anyone, any idea? Thanks

Comment: Do you own the server? Your hosting company might block `print_r($GLOBALS)` for security reasons.

Answer (score 9):

To get names of all global variables do this:

```
array_keys($GLOBALS)
```

More docs:

- on array_keys(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php
- on $GLOBALS: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Answer (score 3):

[`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) — References all variables available in global scope also check this [PHP global or $GLOBALS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573847/php-global-or-globals) here you find many important and useful thing about `$GLOBALS`

Answer (score 2):

The reserved [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) variable is an array containing all global variables.

In the array, the keys are variable names and the values are variable values.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there does exist a [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) variable in PHP.

But you can't do a `var_export()` on it. It'll lead to an error like: **Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?**

Comment: If you **DO WANT** to have a [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) then [check this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php#100302)