# Unset pass by reference PHP

Tags: php, pointers

**EDIT**: what if i apply some business logic on an object and then i need a clone of it to go sideways in some other process. Is it more efficient to reapply the business logic, which has a very high chance to have different results, on a new instance of the object or clone the existing one? But if I do $a = $b, objects being passed by reference it's not enough.

Let's take this example:

```
$a = new test();
$b = $a;
$b->setSomeProp('test');
$a->setSomeProp('failed');
echo $b->getSomeProp(); //returns 'failed'
```

and

```
$a = new test();
$b = unserialize(serialize($a));
$b->setSomeProp('test');
$a->setSomeProp('failed');
echo $b->getSomeProp(); //returns 'test'
```

Is there a better way to replace references?

Comment: Objects are always references in PHP. Always! See this http://nativephp.com/archives/4 tutorial I recorded. You don't need references to deal with objects in PHP 5+ something (Don't even remember when this was added). So you can't replace the value. You just change the reference variable alias to something else. Not the original.

Comment: Your second snipped [prints failed here](http://codepad.org/TxCyCtxa); although it's not immediately clear what you're trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: @NullUserException I tried to serialise a var. The snippet was just for example and i specified in the question that the solution must apply to objects.

Comment: @Udan Then show us a snippet with: the expected output (and why it was expected), the actual output (including errors, if any), and what you're trying to accomplish. Because as it is the question makes no sense.

Comment: Is it more clear after this edit? I can't paste all the code related to the issue but in a few words... in my case is a finite state AI which pulls data from webservices in each state and at some point the client wants to know what would have happened if the aifs would have decided in a different manner.

Comment: @Udan A little, but you're still not demonstrating the problem. See: http://codepad.org/B66G32jN

Comment: your codepad is demonstrating my problem. value of $b->getSomeProp() = $a->setSomeProp

Comment: @Udan Well, if you *don't* want that to happen, why did you set `$b = &$a;`? See: http://codepad.org/ZkrhRIev

Comment: You are right... i messed up aditing the code... but the question remains. Is there any other/better way to replace refference with value?

Comment: Do you mean [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)? eg: http://codepad.org/ZkrhRIev (ps: it's reference, not "refference")

Comment: yes... i mean clone. i just missed that somehow. thank you very much. and sorry for the bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see your code has changed. What you're looking for is `clone`.
Try this:

```
$b = clone $a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to [unset the reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php)

Just use `unset($b)`

Comment: I don't want to unset($b)... i need both

Answer (score 0):

See: [PHP global or $GLOBALS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573847/php-global-or-globals)

From @Artefacto:
"Inside a function, if you want to unset a global variable, you must use unset($GLOBALS['varname']), not global $varname; unset($varname);."