# Undefined index:Type with $GLOBAL variable

Tags: php, global, undefined-index

I set a Super global variable `$GLOBALS['Type']="JobSeeker"` but in another file that variable is not accessed While Running Program am getting `Undefined Index:Type`.

**Page1.php**:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","job1");
// Specify the query to execute
$sql = "select * from JobSeeker_registration where JobSeekerId='".$ID."'  ";
// Execute query
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
// Loop through each records 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


$GLOBALS['Name']=$row['JobSeekerName'];

$GLOBALS['Email']=$row['Email'];

$GLOBALS['Approval']="Confirm";

$GLOBALS['Type']="JobSeeker";
.
.
.
.
include '../Mailing/MailSending.php';
```

**MailSending.php:**

```
if($GLOBALS['Type']=="JobSeeker")  //Here is Error:-Undefined Index of Type
{
    if($GLOBALS['Approval']=="Pending")
    {
        $UserName=$GLOBALS['Email'];
        $mail->addAddress($UserName, $GLOBALS['Name']);
        $mail->Subject = 'Registration Mail';
        $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents("Mailing/Pending.html"), __DIR__);
        $GLOBALS['Email']="";
        $GLOBALS['Type']="";
        $GLOBALS['Name']="";
        $GLOBALS['Approval']="";
    }
    elseif ($GLOBALS['Approval']=="Confirm") 
    {
        $UserName=$GLOBALS['Email'];
        $mail->addAddress($UserName, $GLOBALS['Name']);
        $mail->Subject = 'Registration Confirmation Mail';
        $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents("Mailing/Confirm.html"), __DIR__);
        $GLOBALS['Email']="";
        $GLOBALS['Type']="";
        $GLOBALS['Name']="";
        $GLOBALS['Approval']="";
    }
}
```

I tried with Different Names But did not get any solution.

Comment: Did you include the file required for that? I think you are confusing this with sessions. What does `echo "<pre>";print_r($GLOBALS);` give you?

Comment: Page2.php is the MailSending.php and Page1.php is present in one folder and MailSending.php is present in another, I included MailSending.php in Page1.php.

Comment: That should work. Are you sure you haven't included this file somewhere above in the script or maybe unset the index before including this file?

Comment: You should avoid using $GLOBALS and find more appropriate ways of dealing with the data, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573847/php-global-or-globals and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and may help.

Comment: @vivek_23 I did not unset the index but I included the same file in another file other than Page1.php,  is anything wrong for including the same file in two or more files

Comment: @shiva7890 So, this error doesn't occur form here and rather from that other file in which you have included `MailSending.php` since you may not have set those `$GLOBALS` there. I hope you are not trying to confuse global variables with session variables though.

Comment: @vivek_23  wrote the same code(Page1.php) in another file where I included MailSending.php for sending "Pending mail". It works fine There but here is getting the error.

Comment: @shiva7890 With the code you provided, it should work absolutely fine without any issues. Not sure why it wouldn't.

Comment: okay bro thank you for responding to my question and I will try in another way without using globals

Comment: @vivek_23 I got a solution,$GLOBALS must be assigned in the present file i.e., where we are including a MailSending.php, Actually, I Define $GLOBALS in Page1.php and MailSending.php is included in another PHP file that's why I got the error.

Comment: @shiva7890 Reason why I said that maybe you are confusing this with session variables where you are assuming it will be automatically available once it is set on some file.

Comment: @vivek_23 yes, You said correctly I assumed that if a variable is set in one file those are available in all files. Thank you..!